# Modifying R package data

Tags: r

The bio.infer package contains a data frame /usr/lib/R/library/bio.infer/data/itis.ttable.rda that needs to be modified.

After loading the bio.infer package and attaching the data frame with the
data() function, I wrote the data frame to a text file with write.table().

Using emacs I added another row to the data frame then applied read.table() to
create a data frame, but it's in my pwd, not the R library data subdirectory
for the bio.infer package.

What is the R function to copy/save/write either the text file or the
local copy of itis.ttable to /usr/lib/R/library/bio.infer/data/itis.ttable.rda? I've looked in the R docs and my library of R books without seeing how to add this row to the library's data frame.

Comment: Why do you want to change the data that comes with the package rather than creating a new copy? For one thing, if you update the package you'll just end up losing your changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `load` and `save` with rda files.

```
#Path to the data file
fname <- system.file("data", "itis.ttable.rda", package = "bio.infer")
stopifnot(file.exists(fname))

#Load data into new environment
e <- new.env()
load(fname, envir = e)

#Manipulate it
e$itis.ttable <- rev(e$itis.ttable) #or whatever

#Write back to file
save(itis.ttable, file = fname, envir = e)
```

Though as David Robinson mentioned, you probably shouldn't be overwriting the copy in the package.  It is likely more sensible to make your own copy.

Comment: Thank you, Richie. There are two reasons for editing the data that came with the package: 1) to add a taxon that is not in the data frame and 2) because other bio.infer functions use that data frame and not the one in my project subdirectory.