# Where to store data for an R package hosted on GitHub

Tags: r, github, package

I'm working on building a package in R and have a couple very large data sets that I would like to make available to package users without having to re-run my code that extracted the data initially. My package (which is *still a work in progress*) is hosted on GitHub. It's primarily for my own use as I work on a larger research project. Is there a way to include a .csv of a data set so that it stays stored on GitHub? Ideally it would be something like the default data sets mtcars or diamonds. Is there a way to dput() the data set and then store it in my package function file?

Additional information: I've been using a combination of roxygen2 and devtools to build and launch. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585972/best-way-to-get-necessary-external-data-for-an-r-package) question is related but is one step ahead of what I need.

I hope my question is clear!

Comment: The standard practice is to `save` as an rda file and put in a data subdirectory of your package.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711277/modifying-r-package-data

Comment: Put the csv files in the `inst` folder of your package--is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I do not know what you consider a large dataset, but if you are considering submitting your package to CRAN you should read: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/CRAN-package-sizes-td3303606.html

Comment: I found some documentation that indicated I should put the data set (which is a .rda file) into the data folder of the package. Check. However, when I try to use data(myfile.rda) after installing/loading my package I get an error about a magic number. Does data() not work with packages that aren't on CRAN? @AnandaMahto ?

Comment: @Nancy, using an R data file is generally the way to go, but your package can also include such files in the "inst" folder, and can be accessed using `system.file`. For example, in [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) I have a CSV in the "inst" folder called "concatDT.csv". I can access this with: `system.file("concatDT.csv", package = "SOfun")`. Regarding your use of the .rda files, make sure your DESCRIPTION file has lazy-load set to "true", and then you should be able to access the dataset by the original object's name that was assigned when creating the rda file.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Okay that's really helpful. What is the difference in functionality between inst and data? I want users to be able to use the data set however they want, but also I want to be able to include it in packaged functions. Also, I want LazyData and LazyLoad to be true, right?

Comment: I'm also still having problems with the "magic number". Ugh.

Comment: @Nancy, the rda (or RData) formats would be compressed, so if your datasets are large (and in their final form) that would be preferable. Regarding your "magic number" problem, I'm *assuming* that your rda file is the result of you doing something like `save(myDataSetThatIWantToSave, file = "myfile.rda", compress = TRUE)`. The "magic number" error is usually if a file extension claims that it is one type but the file is actually not of that type (if I remember correctly).